# FFmpeg remove subtitles from file "if exists"

Tags: ffmpeg, subtitle

I have bunch of mp4 files in a folder, Some of them have embedded subtitles and i want to remove them (remove subtitle from file), But the problem is some of files doesn't have subtitle so I'm looking for some if statement in a for loop:

```
for n in *.mp4; do ffmpeg -i n -map 0 -map -0:s -c copy n; done
```

This command apply on all files but i only need to excute it for files that have subtitles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First test for presence of subtitle and then execute remux.

```
for n in *.mp4; do ffmpeg -i "$n" -map 0:s -c copy -f null - && ffmpeg -i "$n" -map 0 -map -0:s -c copy "out_$n"; done
```

Comment: I dont know why i'm getting "in: No such file or directory" even though i changed "in" to "n" but still same error

Comment: I just meant to show you the template for one file. But I've switched to input to vars now.

Comment: if you see this, How do i override the original file with output correctly? I changed the "out_$n" to "$n" then ffmpeg ask me for accepting the override, But ffmpeg deprecate the file and not playble. Errors: 

FFmpg file same as Input #0 - exiting
FFmpeg cannot edit existing files in-place.

Comment: Output file cannot be same as input; has to be different.

Answer (score 0):

just to close the last **MwThreex** question:

for n in *.mp4; do ffmpeg -i "$n" -map 0:s -c copy -f null - && ffmpeg -i "$n" -map 0 -map -0:s -c copy "out_$n" **&& rm "$n" && mv "out_$n" "$n"** ; done